# Pymongo find value in subdocuments

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using MongoDB 4 and Python 3. I have 3 collections. The first collection got 2 referenced fields on the other collections.

**Example :**

```
User {
   _id  : ObjectId("5b866e8e06a77b30ce272ba6"),
   name : "John",
   pet  : ObjectId("5b9248cc06a77b09a496bad0"),
   car  : ObjectId("5b214c044ds32f6bad7d2"),
}

Pet {
   _id  : ObjectId("5b9248cc06a77b09a496bad0"),
   name : "Mickey",
}

Car {
   _id   : ObjectId("5b214c044ds32f6bad7d2"),
   model : "Tesla"
}
```

So one User has one car and one pet. I need to query the User collection and find if there is a User who has a Pet with the name "Mickey" and a Car with the model "Tesla".

I tried this :

```
db.user.aggregate([{
    $project : {"pet.name" : "Mickey", "car.model" : "Tesla"  } 
}])
```

But it returns me lot of data while I have just one document with this data. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: what should be the expected output?

Comment: I just want to know if the document exist in my collection. But the output can be just a boolean or all `User` properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer posted by @AnthonyWinzlet has the downside that it needs to churn through all documents in the users collection and perform `$lookup`s which is relatively costly. So depending on the size of your `Users` collection it may well be faster to do this:

1. Put an index on `users.pet` and `users.car`: `db.users.createIndex({pet: 1, car: 1})`
2. Put an index on `cars.model`: `db.cars.createIndex({model: 1})`
3. Put an index on `pets.name`: `db.pets.createIndex({name: 1})`

Then you could simply do this:

1. Get the list of all matching `"Tesla"` cars: `db.cars.find({model: "Tesla"})`
2. Get the list of all matching `"Mickey"` pets: `db.pets.find({name: "Mickey"})`
3. Find the users you are interested in: `db.users.find({car: { $in: [<ids from cars query>] }, pet: { $in: [<ids from pets query>] }})`

That is pretty easy to read and understand plus all three queries are fully covered by indexes so they can be expected to be as fast as things can get.

Comment: Hey. I already do this before. I have all my indexes and I did 3 queries and I want to try with one query to compare who is faster

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation here.

Something like this

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Pet.collection.name,
    "let": { "pet": "$pet" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$pet"] }, "name" : "Mickey"}}
    ],
    "as": "pet"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Car.collection.name,
    "let": { "car": "$car" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$car"] }, "model" : "Tesla"}}
    ],
    "as": "car"
  }},
  { "$match": { "pet": { "$ne": [] }, "car": { "$ne": [] } }},
  { "$project": { "name": 1 }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But the query is slow :/. There is a way to speed up ? For example just return a boolean if the document exists or not. And I tried with and without unwind I have the same result except without the query is faster

Comment: Does your user collection have more fields? If yes then use projection(`$project`) here and yes we can remove `$unwind` stages here.

Comment: I have 9 fields

Comment: Using projection might help you... No other option

Comment: Can you give an example please ?

Comment: Ok I have updated the answer. That's only the way to do I think

Comment: If you're after performance then add an index on the cars collection `{ model: 1 }` and on the pets collection `{ name: 1 }` and use the updated query above.

Comment: @dnickless thanks... Indexing will work here but not sure how above modification in the query will be performative!!!

Comment: In the way the query was structured before my change, MongoDB could not use an index for the last `$match` stage. Now it can! And since we're filtering out lots of documents in the `$lookup`, there's less data flowing through the pipeline which might help, too.

Comment: You might be right... Here's my thinking: In the way the query was structured before my change, MongoDB could not use an index for the last `$match` stage. Now it can! And since we're filtering out lots of documents in the `$lookup`, there's less data flowing through the pipeline which might help, too. Admittedly, we're still comparing stuff in the last `$match` stage but at least it's not strings. I'm hoping, checking for an empty array is faster.

Comment: It's pretty faster now ! But I don't understand why the last line  `{ "$project": { "name": 1 }}`

Comment: Ok so before when I do the @dnickless way I finish my loop in 47 seconds and with the aggregate more than 5 min... xD Atleast there is a way to speed up the aggregate, do this in 3 queries is the best way

Comment: @John Well `$lookup` performs left join So it will only be productive if there is a `$match` condition at the starting of the pipeline which you don't have. So it is better to use three queries instead.

Comment: @John: How many records are we talking about here? And what's in your loop? There's no way that running the three queries takes 47s if you've got the indexes right...

Comment: It's normal I think. The loop is on 20 000 items but it's on Informix object. I do query on Informix database and I think it takes 47 sec cause of this

Comment: @John use @ to notify dnickless

Comment: @John try to remove the loop and go set based if possible. Or post another question on SO where you explain the looping bit.

Comment: @dnickless remove the loop for what ? I don't understand. I'm using this library to query informix database https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy I have the same loop if you look at the `while dictionary != False:`

Comment: @dnickless In fact, if I remove all the code who query mongoDB the loop takes 5 secondes.