# Speed up Pymongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, optimization

I'm using Python 3, Pymongo with mongodb 4.0 and [Ifxpy](https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy) to query Informix database. I have 4 Collections in my MongoDB database :

- User
- Office
- Pet
- Car

One User has one Office, one Pet and one Car. So I have 3 references on each field in the User collections.

I need something like this :

- I want to find if there is a User with the name `John` and a Pet with the name `Mickey` and a Car with the model `Tesla` and with the status `inactive`. After that I'll just update the User status to `active`. I have to query the Office but I don't use it in this example.

I created indexes for each fields :

```
office.create_index([("code", pymongo.DESCENDING)], unique=True)
pet.create_index([("name", pymongo.DESCENDING)], unique=True)
car.create_index([("model", pymongo.DESCENDING)], unique=True)
user.create_index([("username", pymongo.DESCENDING)], unique=True)
user.create_index([("pet", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
user.create_index([("car", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
user.create_index([("status", pymongo.DESCENDING)])
```

Here is my code :

```
office_id = None
car_id = None
pet_id = None
ifx_connection = IfxPy.connect(ifx_param, "", "")
stmt = IfxPy.exec_immediate(ifx_connection, sql)
dictionary = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt) # Get data key / value
start = time.time()

# Loop on informix data (20 000 items)
while dictionary != False:
    # Trim all string in dict
    dictionary = {k: v.strip() if isinstance(v, str) else v for k,v in dictionary.items()}

    # Get office
    office_code = dictionary['office_code']
    existing_office = office.find_one({"code": office_code})

    if bool(existing_office):
        office_id = existing_office['_id']

    # Get pet
    existing_pet = pet.find_one({"name": dictionary['pet_name']})
    if bool(existing_pet):
        pet_id = existing_pet['_id']

    # Get car
    existing_car = car.find_one({"model": dictionary['car_model']})

    if bool(existing_car):
        car_id = existing_car['_id']

    # Get user
    existing_user = user.find_one({
        "username": dictionary['username'],
        "car": car_id,
        "pet": pet_id,
        "status" : "inactive"
    })

    if bool(existing_user):
        # Change user status
        user.update_one({'_id': existing_user['_id']}, {"$set": {"status" : "active"}}, upsert=False)

    # Next row
    dictionary = IfxPy.fetch_assoc(stmt)
```

If I remove the MongoDB code from the loop, it takes 1,33 seconds. And If I query MongoDB it takes 47 seconds. I have 20 000 items. I think it's really slow.

I tried to see the time for each find_one with `start = time.time()`
 by removing all find_one and let just one. And if I let just Office find_one it takes ~12 seconds and same for the other. If I let just customer find_one it takes ~12 seconds too. So ~12 * 4 this is why it takes ~47 seconds for all find_one.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Index collections to support your queries.

Comment: Sorry I already have indexes. I'll edit

Comment: Sorry, just realised you do 20k queries to each collection, which is like half a milli per query.  I doubt you can make it quicker unless you change the app. E.g. load all offices into local list in one go and then check if it exists without touching mongo.

Comment: I can't do that because if you watch the find_one on the user I need to check multiple properties : username car_id and pet_id

Comment: I created this question because @dnickless asked me to explain my loop : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52371589/2519631 because it's not normal to wait 47 seconds

Comment: I [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078244/mongodb-optimize-multiple-find-one-insert-inside-loop/52117885#52117885) these things...

Comment: @juvian Yes I rewatched this question but as I said I need to get the associated pet_id and car_id

Comment: I already mentioned how to get the associated pet_ids, and similar code could be used for cars

Comment: @juvian the pet_id and the car_id should be at the same row. I think I have to show you what I have in my informix query. How can we open a chat ?

Comment: @juvian https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180274/speed-up-mongodb come in my room

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up that algorithm you'd need to reduce the number of MongoDB queries which you can do by leveraging what you know about your data. So, if you e.g. know that you only have a few distinct offices or if you are likely to query all of them anyway at some stage (or the same ones over and over) then you'd probably want to load all offices in one preliminary step outside of the loop (!!!) and cache them using a dictionary for a fast lookup inside the loop without requiring another database round-trip. The same for pets and cars.

So, more precisely, I would:

1. run the informix query the way you do it already
2. retrieve all offices, pets and cars using three upfront queries. If you want to optimize this stage you'd only retrieve the ones that are contained in the distinct values of the respective column in your informix dataset. Also make sure you add a projection to only include the `name`/`model`/`code` + the `_id` fields in the output in order to reduce the amount of BSON processing involved
3. put the returned values into three dictionaries (`name`->`_id`, `model`->`_id`, `code`->`_id`)
4. loop through the informix result set the way you do it already
5. for every user in your informix result set append an update model to a list where the selection criterion is made up of all the previously gathered details and the update part is static
6. outside (after) the loop use a [bulk update](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#ordered-bulk-write-operations) to update all users

Comment: Thank you so much for your support you helped me a lot